# Get iPad/iPhone info using only its UDID?

Tags: ios, ipad

Is it possible to get an iOS device info by just using its UDID?
Info such as the iPad model, OS, etc.

I have a developer account where I register apple devices using its UDID, but how do I extract information for such devices?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no because it is generated from a lot of variables. As per Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDID) [on] devices introduced between 2007 and 2018 it was represented as a 40-digit lowercase hex code, and for device models introduced after 2018, as a 25-digit uppercase hex code.